# How to build docker image from github repository

Tags: redis, docker

In official docs we can see:

```
# docker build github.com/creack/docker-firefox
```

It just works fine to me. `docker-firefox` is a repository and has `Dockerfile` within root dir.
Then I want to buid redis image and exact version 2.8.10 :

```
# docker build github.com/docker-library/redis/tree/99c172e82ed81af441e13dd48dda2729e19493bc/2.8.10
2014/11/05 16:20:32 Error trying to use git: exit status 128 (Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/docker-build-git067001920/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/docker-library/redis/tree/99c172e82ed81af441e13dd48dda2729e19493bc/2.8.10/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
)
```

I got error above. What's the right format with build docker image from github repos?

Comment: Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`docker build url#ref:dir`

> Git URLs accept context configuration in their fragment section,
> separated by a colon :. The first part represents the reference that
> Git will check out, this can be either a branch, a tag, or a commit
> SHA. The second part represents a subdirectory inside the repository
> that will be used as a build context.
>
> For example, run this command to use a directory called docker in the
> branch container:

```
docker build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git#container:docker
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: For those who may be confused with `docker build url#ref:dir`, `ref` here means branch

Answer (score 11):

The thing you specified as repo URL is not a valid git repository. You will get error when you will try

> `git clone github.com/docker-library/redis/tree/99c172e82ed81af441e13dd48dda2729e19493bc/2.8.10`

Valid URL for this repo is `github.com/docker-library/redis`. So you may want to try following:

> `docker build github.com/docker-library/redis`

But this will not work too. To build from github, docker requires `Dockerfile` in repository root, howerer, this repo doesn't provide this one. So, I suggest, you only have to clone this repo and build image using local Dockerfile.

Comment: In fact `docker build https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/redis/master/2.8.10/Dockerfile` works, but not like the [official example](http://docs.docker.com/v1.1/reference/commandline/cli/#build). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

One can use the following example which sets up a Centos 7 container for testing ORC file format. Make sure to escape the `#` sign:

`$ docker build https://github.com/apache/orc.git\#:docker/centos7 -t orc-centos7`

Comment: The "-t" flag and name is important in order the image gets a name set. Otherwise you'll end up with <none> images.

Comment: I don't know why it fails on my computer. The error says "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: subdir not supported yet". I'm using Docker-CE-20.10