# How could we build a docker image from a github repository?

Tags: git, docker, github

We are following the steps written in this tutorial to get a docker image from a github repository:

https://github.com/es-comunidad-intersystems/webinar-gestion-apis

After downloading the git repository with:

```
git clone https://github.com/es-comunidad-intersystems/webinar-gestion-apis.git
```

We would need to build the image from the downloaded repository with the following command:

```
$ docker build . --tag webinar-gestion-apis:stable --no-cache
```

However, after writting the previous command, the output is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  754.2kB
Step 1/9 : FROM intersystems/iris:2019.3.0.302.0
pull access denied for intersystems/iris, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

We have also read:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

And we have used:

```
$ docker build - < Dockerfile
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/9 : FROM intersystems/iris:2019.3.0.302.0
pull access denied for intersystems/iris, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Also:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  754.2kB
Step 1/9 : FROM intersystems/iris:2019.3.0.302.0
pull access denied for intersystems/iris, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

In addition we have tried to sign up in Docker Hub, and then log in via command line and issue the previous commands, with the same result.

Plus, we have also tried to build it from the github repository directly as:

```
$ docker build https://github.com/es-comunidad-intersystems/webinar-gestion-apis.git
Sending build context to Docker daemon  642.6kB
Step 1/9 : FROM intersystems/iris:2019.3.0.302.0
pull access denied for intersystems/iris, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

In addition we have read:

- [How to build docker image from github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753030/how-to-build-docker-image-from-github-repository/39194765)
- [Docker Hub Registry cannot build docker image from Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373487/docker-hub-registry-cannot-build-docker-image-from-github-repository)

EDIT: Besides we have written the following command to run the containers in the background:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Being the output:

```
Creating network "webinar-gestion-apis_default" with the default driver
Pulling iris (webinar-gestion-apis:stable)...
The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling iris (webinar-gestion-apis:stable)...
pull access denied for webinar-gestion-apis, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

How could we build a docker image from a github repository?

Comment: Those instructions say to run `docker load -i iris-2019.3.0.302.0-docker.tar.gz`, which is presumably made available during the webinar. Have you done this?